# reward points and allocate those points in the original table's field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table here : [image]

I want to reward a gold and a silver(i.e a value of 1 wherever applicable,else 0 )to top 2 persons by looking at pointsRewarded field.

I already have the first table created .I have modified it with the extra fields that I want i.e rank,gold,silver fields.It has null values now.

i want the output to be something like this: 
[image]

I have tried some query :

```
update dbo.original
set rnk = dense_rank() over (partition by WeekNumber order by   pointsrewarded desc)

set gold =
   case when rnk = '1' then 1 else 0 end 
set silver =
   case when rnk = '2' then 1 else 0 end
```

**I already have modified the table design by adding the rnk,gold and silver fields.I want the values  generated by the query to go and sit in those fields.**

**Please help me with the query or give me some suggestions on how to proceed.Please.**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a follow-up to your earlier question.

In SQL Server you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select o.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by WeekNumber order by   pointsrewarded desc) as new_rnk
      from dbo.original
     )
update toupdate
set rnk = new_rank,
    gold = (case when rnk = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
    silver = (case when rnk = 2 then 1 else 0 end);
```

Note:  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use single quotes for numeric constants.

Comment: Thanks a ton. U saved a lot of my time.Genius..!!